# Unparseable date in java -convert from Date into Calendar

Tags: java, date, calendar

I need to convert from `Date(the object :insuree.getBirthDate())`  into `Calendar(the object : request_MDP.setBIRTH_DATE)`

but i get the error :

> 21/02/13 15:20:26 ERROR [MdmInsureeService]: ServiceProxy Update
>   exception: 'Unparseable date: "Mon Nov 15 15:00:00 IST 1982"' 21/02/13
>   15:20:26 ERROR [MdmInsureeService]: ServiceProxy Update exception
>   (toString): 'java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Nov 15
>   15:00:00 IST 1982"

This is my code :

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date date_MDP =(Date)formatter.parse(insuree.getBirthDate().toString()); 
Calendar cal_MDP=Calendar.getInstance();
cal_MDP.setTime(date_MDP);
request_MDP.setBIRTH_DATE(cal_MDP);
```

How can I convert the `Date(insuree.getBirthDate())` into `Calendar(setBIRTH_DATE)` ?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `cal_MDP.setTime(insuree.getBirthDate());`

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("KK:mm aa");
    Date date = df.parse("10:30 PM");
    System.out.print(date);
    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
    System.out.print(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: i get this error log :21/02/13 15:51:49 ERROR [MdmInsureeService]: ServiceProxy Update exception: 'Unparseable date: "Mon Nov 15 15:00:00 IST 1982"'
21/02/13 15:51:49 ERROR [MdmInsureeService]: ServiceProxy Update exception (toString): 'java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Nov 15 15:00:00 IST 1982"

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you run this code on a system with a non-English locale? Such a locale might not recognize the weekday or month in your example date ("Mon Nov 15 15:00:00 IST 1982"), because it uses different names (e.g. "Tue" would be "Di" in German).

Replace the first line in your snippet with

```
DateFormat formatter = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
```

and it will work with your example date. Either way, you have to use the same format **and** locale that was used to generate those date strings. Maybe you can even convince the generator to use some standard format like [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

Comment: i get this error log :    21/02/13 15:51:49 ERROR [MdmInsureeService]: ServiceProxy Update exception: 'Unparseable date: "Mon Nov 15 15:00:00 IST 1982"' 21/02/13 15:51:49 ERROR [MdmInsureeService]: ServiceProxy Update exception (toString): 'java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Nov 15 15:00:00 IST 1982"

Comment: What happens if you run the following statement in your environment? `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US).parse("Mon Nov 15 15:00:00 IST 1982");`

Comment: i cant compile it , i have error :Type mismatch: cannot convert from Date to DateFormat